# "No safari Extensions Certificate" error on Mac

Tags: ios, macos, safari

I have followed [these](http://knackforge.com/blog/karalmax/how-create-safari-extension-certificate) steps to create a certificate for building safari extensions. On my developer account it is showing expiry date to be 10th May 2017. My certificate file is on my desktop. i had double clicked it and now the certificate is also showing in my keychain access.

But whenever i open Extension builder it show NO SAFARI EXTENSIONS CERTIFICATE.

Do I need to upload that downloaded certificate in safari somewhere or elsewhere?

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I myself have got the answer.
For Mac users, just update your OSX and safari to the latest version.
And the certificate will get detected.

Whether to update OSX or safari see [this](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204416)

Comment: Well, that is a strange behavior then. Sad that Apple don't provide a better a better notification about this particular issue via Safari, etc. But I wonder do you really need to upgrade OS X & Safari or just one or the other is ok?

Comment: Safari is included with OS X. To get the most recent version of Safari, install the most recent version of OS X from the Mac App Store. Ref: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204416

Comment: Yes, but except for major Safari upgrades that require a matching OS X upgrade to get it, generally on a non-latest OS X, you can simply just upgrade Safari via App Store or Apple site.

Comment: Btw, I've never had certs problem that required a Safari & OS X upgrade, but that was several years back. So either Apple changed things now, since they merged the free Safari Developer program into a single Apple developer program you have to pay for, or you encountered some bug.

Comment: if it would have been bug, then merely doing system updates wouldn't have solved my problem

Comment: not necessarily, it could have been a Safari or OS X bug that got fixed by an update, e.g. bug in older version. And could be a bug in older versions due to Apple's change in terms for the Safari developer program and its certificates.

Comment: ohh..so you were saying about these types of bugs, i thought other way
yes definitely this could be the case

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on OS X 10.10, and I didn't want to upgrade the OS. Turns out that I had an update for Safari pending (to version 9.1.1). Once the Safari update was done, the extension builder picked up the certificate right away.